Looking for 2F1 Hypergeometric identity
The hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ can be rewritten using Euler and Pfaff transformations in the following way:
\begin{equation}
(1-z)^k \quad _2F_1\left(-k,1,\frac{k+3}{2},\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
=\quad  _2F_1\left(-k,\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{k+3}{2},z\right)
\end{equation}
What I would like to know is whether there is a similar relationship to the previous one to simplify the following expression:
\begin{equation}
(1-z)^k \quad _2F_1\left(-k,\frac{1+k}{2},\frac{k+3}{2},\frac{A z}{z-1}\right)
\end{equation}
in the case where k is a positive integer and A is a positive real number.Any suggestions or advice is welcome.
There are two reasons behind this question. The first reason concerns the generalization of the formula above to determine the effect of the dilatation operator (take a look at the paper G. Dattoli, P. Ottaviani, A. Torre and L. Vasquez, Rivista del Nuovo Cimento Vol. 20, No. 2 (1997) 3). The second reason concerns the possibility of simplifying the following expression:
\begin{equation}
A (1-z)^k\; _2F_1\left(-k,\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{k+3}{2},\frac{A z}{z-1}\right)+(2-A) (z+1)^k\; _2F_1\left(-k,\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{k+3}{2},\frac{(2-A) z}{z+1}\right)
\end{equation}
Digging further, I noticed an interesting property that might be useful in responding to this post. If I define A as follows:
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{2 k_2^2}{k_1^2+k_2^2}
\end{equation}
It is possible to rewrite the expression above as:
\begin{equation}
f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)=k_2^2 (1-\phi )^r \, _2F_1\left(-r,\frac{r+1}{2};\frac{r+3}{2};\frac{2 k_2^2 \phi }{\left(k_1^2+k_2^2\right) (\phi
   -1)}\right)+k_1^2 (\phi +1)^r \, _2F_1\left(-r,\frac{r+1}{2};\frac{r+3}{2};\frac{2 k_1^2 \phi }{\left(k_1^2+k_2^2\right)
   (\phi +1)}\right)
\end{equation}
I noticed that $f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)$ has the following property:
\begin{equation}
f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)=\frac{1}{2} \left(k_1 \frac{\partial f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)}{\partial k_1}+k_2 \frac{\partial f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)}{\partial k_2}\right)
\end{equation}
If we ignore the fact that we know $f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)$, can the solution of this differential equation allow $f(k_1,k_2,\phi,r)$ to be simplified?

I'm not certain why you are needing to simplify your function down further - at this point, you have already reached a point where you can convert this function into a polynomial, if $k$ is a positive integer.
By the DLMF 15.2.4, if $m$ is a positive integer and $c$ is not a negative integer:
$$_2F_1\left(-m,b;c;z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{(-m)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}z^n=\sum_{n=0}^m(-1)^n\binom{m}{n}\frac{(b)_n}{(c)_n}z^n$$
In your case, both those conditions hold, so:
$$(1-z)^k\;_2F_1\left( -k,\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{k+3}{2};\frac{Az}{z-1} \right)=(1-z)^k\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^n\binom{k}{n}\frac{\left( \frac{k+1}{2} \right)_n}{\left( \frac{k+3}{2} \right)_n}\left( \frac{Az}{z-1} \right)^n$$
That leaves some pretty nasty Pochhammer functions, but seeing as their main argument differs by one, we can plug those into Wolfram Alpha to get a simplification of:
$$(1-z)^k\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^n\binom{k}{n}\frac{\left( \frac{k+1}{2} \right)_n}{\left( \frac{k+3}{2} \right)_n}\left( \frac{Az}{z-1} \right)^n=(1-z)^k\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^n\binom{k}{n}\frac{k+1}{k+2n+1}\left( \frac{Az}{z-1} \right)^n$$
Which seems a perfectly reasonable polynomial to calculate!

you have $(-1)^i$, where $i$ is not defined. I suppose it must be replaced by $n$.

You are correct, that's an error! I'll fix that!
